# Find file based on portions of the name: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

How do I find a file or folder based on portions of the name? for instance:

I have two products A and B which both have Serial Numbers SN1 and SN2 respectively. I also know the value of X but I do not know the values of date and time.
I want to find the file name which is inside of a folder called A_SN1_B_SN2_date_time_stationX
the name of the file is similar as A_SN1_B_SN2_date_time_stationX_log.rtf

How do I find these without knowing date or time???

Answer (score 0):

Python can search for file names in a easy way using the OS package

```
    import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
   result = []

# Wlaking top-down from the root
   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return result

print(find_files("smpl.htm","D:"))
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the filename!!! The filename contains some characters that change such as time and date. How do I extract the name of files/folders within a selected directory?